# How to put button right next to input box using bootstrap columns/grid system?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, razor, bootstrap-4

How am I able to put a button right next to the input box given that I'm using bootstrap columns/grid system? The `Label` is of 2, `EditorFor` div of 4 and the `input` div of 6. If I lower the `EditorFor` div to 3, it brings the `input/button` div closer in, but it shrinks the width of the `EditorFor`

The style `style = "border: 1px solid red;"` is just for debugging.

[Image of what the layout currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9KJw.png)

[Example of `EditorFor` been set to 3 and shrinking the input width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlL7w.png)

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tag.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", style = "border: 1px solid red;" })
            <div class="col-md-4" style = "border: 1px solid red;">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tag.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tag.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" style = "border: 1px solid red;">
                <input type="submit" value="Add Tag" class="btn btn-default" style = "border: 1px solid red;"/>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

- Extra detail

Here is the html output:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Tag_Name" style="border: 1px solid red;">Tag Name:</label>
            <div class="col-md-4" style = "border: 1px solid red;">
                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="Tag cannot be longer than 50 characters." data-val-length-max="50" data-val-regex="Must start with a capital letter, only alphabetic characters and no spaces allowed." data-val-regex-pattern="^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z&quot;&#39;\s-]*$" data-val-required="The Tag Name: field is required." id="Tag_Name" name="Tag.Name" type="text" value="" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Tag.Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" style = "border: 1px solid red;">
                <input type="submit" value="Add Tag" class="btn btn-default" style = "border: 1px solid red;"/>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Does it show a margin or padding if you inspect the input?

Comment: Are you using form-row?  It narrows some gutters

Comment: Nup, I just supplied the html output.
Not using form-row.

Comment: Try wrapping the columns in a div with class form-row. If it doesn't help it could be useful to inspect the gap and see whats creating it.

Comment: It looks like ```@Html.EditorFor``` has a maximum width. Meaning it's never going to reach the width of col-md-4 or above.So I'd either need to increase the maximum width for ```@Html.EditorFor``` to fill up for col-md-4, or use col-md-3 to bring the button closer to the input. 
I take it the gap that there is for example between the start of the col and the button is bootstrap's default padding/margin.

Answer (score 0):

Use [input group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/input-group/) for bringing button right next to the input box.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Tag_Name" style="border: 1px solid red;">Tag Name:</label>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="border: 1px solid red;">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="Tag cannot be longer than 50 characters." data-val-length-max="50" data-val-regex="Must start with a capital letter, only alphabetic characters and no spaces allowed." data-val-regex-pattern="^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z&quot;&#39;\s-]*$"
          data-val-required="The Tag Name: field is required." id="Tag_Name" name="Tag.Name" type="text" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Tag.Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <input type="submit" value="Add Tag" class="btn btn-default" style="border: 1px solid red;" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `@Html.EditorFor` has a maximum width. Meaning it's never going to reach the width of `col-md-4` or above. So I'd either need to increase the maximum width for `@Html.EditorFor` to fill up for `col-md-4`, or use `col-md-3` to bring the button closer to the input.

Using `col-md-3` creates the problem that the width of `EditorFor` shrinks (in relation to proceeding `EditorFor`) because of bootstrap's column/grid system padding.

[image: Image showing Bootstrap's col padding]

In that case, removing the `padding-right` / setting it to `0` removes this gap making it so `EditorFor` now fills up the the right side of the col.

[image: The final result]

Final code:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tag.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", style = "border: 1px solid red;" })
        <div class="col-md-3" style="border: 1px solid red; padding-right:0;">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tag.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tag.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7" style="border: 1px solid red;">
            <input type="submit" value="Add Tag" class="btn btn-default" style="border: 1px solid red;" />
        </div>
    </div>
```